# How to print formatted statement in three separate lines?

Tags: python, printing, format

I have a formatted print statement that I want to print in three separate lines.  The code is below:

```
sender = 'tim@abc.com'
recipient = 'tom@xyz.org'
subject = 'Hello!'

print('From: {} To: {} subject: {}'.format(sender, recipient, subject))
```

Currently it prints like this:

```
From: tim@abc.com To: tom@xyz.org subject: Hello!
```

But I want it to print like this:

```
From: tim@abc.com 
To: tom@xyz.org 
subject: Hello!
```

I thought I could get it to print that like if I put a "sep" function in the print statement like this:

```
sender = 'tim@abc.com'
recipient = 'tom@xyz.org'
subject = 'Hello!'

print('From: {} To: {} subject: {}'.format(sender, recipient, subject), sep = '\n')
```

That did not work though.  Any ideas?  All help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using '\n' directly in the print string

```
a ="aaa"
b="bbb"
c="ccc"
print('From: {}\nTo: {}\nSubject:{}\n'.format(a,b,c))
```

I got this:

```
From: aaa
To: bbb
Subject:ccc
```

In your original setup, you only have a single string, so there is nothing for the separator (i.e. sep) to separate.

Answer (score 1):

The `sep` keywors just works for separate string like following :

```
>>> print('From: {}', 'To: {}', 'subject: {}', sep = '\n')
From: {}
To: {}
subject: {}
```

For an integrate string just sue new line `\n` character inside your string :

```
>>> print('From: {} \nTo: {} \nsubject: {}'.format(sender, recipient, subject))
From: tim@abc.com 
To: tom@xyz.org 
subject: Hello!
```